# Multiple routes to a single controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller/model called `contacts` and I have 2 other models that have a many to many relationship with contacts, ie: `users` and `franchises`.  I have been playing with nested routes and I can make /users/1/contacts work fine but what if I wanted to do /franchises/1/contacts? Is there a dynamic way to solve this? or would I need to do

```
if FRANCHISE
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_franchise_contact_path(@contact) %>
elsif USER
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_contact_path(@contact) %>
end
```

The only other method I can see is making a method in the respective controller that can deal with managing contacts.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about polymorphic urls?

**polymorphic_url(record_or_hash_or_array, options = {})**

```
Constructs a call to a named RESTful route for the given record and returns the resulting URL string. For example:

# calls post_url(post)
polymorphic_url(post) # => "http://example.com/posts/1"
polymorphic_url([blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/blogs/1/posts/1"
polymorphic_url([:admin, blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/admin/blogs/1/posts/1"
polymorphic_url([user, :blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/users/1/blog/posts/1"
polymorphic_url(Comment) # => "http://example.com/comments"
```

In your case: `polymorphic_url([@franchise_or_user, @contact], :action => :edit)`

Or simply: `edit_polymorphic_url([@franchise_or_user, @contact])`

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is if im in /users/1/contacts is there a way to make it `edit_polymorphic_url([@dynamic, @contact])` with out telling it if its a @user or a @franchise?

Comment: you just have to stuff your object into @dynamic - whether it is a user or a contact. Alternatively you could check what params are set:
`if params[:user_id]; object_type = User, object_id = params[:user_id]; elsif params[:franchise_id]; ...; end`

Comment: I was toying around with it and I came to the same conclusion as you.  Thanks a lot.  I had no idea polymorphic_urls existed!

Comment: Yup, they are a nice feature :) Makes stuff easy.